# Recover Jpeg files from raw data

Tags: jpeg, cs50

I need to recover jpeg files from a memory card (raw data). I have done the code below but I am getting a seg fault which i cannot identify the source. Just to summarize, I´ve done a loop to read 512bytes chunks and look for specific jpeg header. If it is the first jpeg, the programa will open a file and keep writing to it. If jpeg is not the first, close previous image and keep writing to it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Check usage
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./recover image\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Open file
    FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (!file)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open %s.\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    // open array to store the chunks with enough memory

    unsigned char buffer [512];

    // variables jpeg count

    int img_count = 0;

    // open filename img to write to

    char filename[8];
    FILE *img = NULL;

    // create loop to read 512 chunks
    while (fread(buffer, 512, 1, file) > 0)
        {
            if (buffer[0] == 0xff && buffer[1] == 0xd8 && buffer[2] == 0xff && (buffer[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0)
            {
                // if theres already a jpeg open
                if (img_count > 0)
                {
                    fclose(img);
                    sprintf(filename, "%i03.jpg", img_count);
                    img = fopen(filename, "w");
                    img_count++;


                } // first jpeg img count == 0
                 else if (img_count == 0)
                {
                    sprintf(filename, "%i03.jpg", img_count);
                    img = fopen(filename, "w");
                    img_count++;

                }

            }
            //if this is not a new jpeg header, just write to img
            if (img_count > 0)
            {
                fwrite(buffer, 512, 1, img);

            }
            else
            {
                continue;

            }

        }
    fclose(img);
    fclose(file);
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: also valgrind shows "/etc/profile.d/cli.sh: line 94: 19528 Segmentation fault " but I have nothing on line 94

Comment: `img` of `fwrite(buffer, 512, 1, img)`  is not a valid FILE pointer.  Your code does not execute `fopen` before calling `fwrite`.   I added some `printf`s to your code and you can see it here with this [link](https://cee.studio/?bucket=200609-3Cl&name=recover). Just click "Start" to compile your code and run it in Terminal.

Comment: Thanks. I´ve modified to add an else if when img_count == 0 (first jepg) and another if to write to the file if no header is detected. I don´t get seg fault anymore but It seems I can´t extract any images (says jpg not found). The new modified code is above.

Comment: I can´t figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

Found it...typo i had "%i03.jpg" instead of %03i.jpg"